# Laravel 5.0 Query Builder - Where with multiple parameters

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

I've a Laravel 5.0 project, that I need to implement the following logic

```
$var1= 'A';
$var2= 'B';
$var3= 50;
$data = DataModel::select('attr1','attr2')->where(function($q){
    $q->where('attr3','like','%'.$var1.'%');
    $q->where('attr4','like',$var2.'%');
    $q->where('attr5','=',$var3);
})->get();
```

The problem is for the "Where" function $var1, var2 and $var3 are undefined variables.

My Question is, How can I pass multiple parameters to the where function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here, closure function passed in where argument. To inherit variables you have to use `use` keyword

For example `function($q) use($var1, $var2, $var3){...`

To learn more about closure function please check php manual.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
$var1= 'A';
$var2= 'B';
$var3= 50;
$data = DataModel::select('attr1','attr2')->where(function($q) use ($var1, $var2, $var3) {
    $q->where('attr3','like','%'.$var1.'%')
        ->orWhere('attr4','like',$var2.'%')
        ->orWhere('attr5','=',$var3);
})->get();
```