# How in laravel eloquent make query with multiple 'and'?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have this query :

```
SELECT * 
FROM `groups` 
WHERE `status` = 1 
    AND `active` != 1 
    AND (`approved` != 1 OR `approved` IS NULL)
```

And I try this in query builder but don't know how to make it properly

Here is my query builder :

```
Group::where([['status', '=', 1], ['active', '!=', 1]])
    ->where([['approved', '!=', 1]])
    ->orWhereNull()
    ->get();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5.0 Query Builder - Where with multiple parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40357023/laravel-5-0-query-builder-where-with-multiple-parameters)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use where with Closure to group params. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#parameter-grouping

```
$data = Group::where(function($query){
        $query
            ->where('approved', '!=', 1)
            ->orWhereNull('approved');
    })
    ->where('status', 1)
    ->where('active', '!=', 1)
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
$articles = \App\Article::where('foo', 'bar')
    ->where('color', 'blue')
    ->orWhere('name', 'like', '%John%')
    ->whereIn('id', [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
    ->get();
```

Comment: Doesn't seem enough to help the author. If he already gave you an example of the code he has, try to work on that and see how you could improve it.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
 Group::where('status', 1)
    ->where('active', '!=', 1)
    ->where(function($query){
       $query->where('approved', '!=', 1)
            ->orWhereNull('approved')
    })->get();
```

use where in closure in laravel [see](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#where-clauses)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Group::where('status', 1)->where('active', '!=', 1)->where('approved', '!=', 1)
->orWhere('status', 1)->where('active', '!=', 1)->where('approved', NULL)
->get();
```

or

```
$x = Group::where(function($q){
        $q->where('approved', '!=', 1)
          ->orWhereNull('approved')
        })
           ->where('status', 1)->where('active', '!=', 1)
           ->get();
```